# How to extract result from LocalSubmit without assignment i.e. from the generated TaskObject

Tags: asynchronous-processing

`LocalSubmit` in the following generates a `TaskObject`. To extract the result one needs an explicit assignment to some var `r'res` via `HandlerFunctions` within `LocalSubmit`.

```
r`res = -1;
r`taskObject = 
 LocalSubmit[(Pause@2; 2), HandlerFunctionsKeys -> "EvaluationResult",
   HandlerFunctions -> <|
    "TaskFinished" -> ((r`res = #EvaluationResult) &)|>]
Dynamic@r`res
```

Is there any way to extract the result from the TaskObject itself rather than via explicit assignment?